# How to check minimum amount is less than maximum amount?

Tags: jquery

I need to check minimum amount is less than maximum amount from minimum input text and maximum input text in the jquery? How can i check ? Here is the method i check. Thanks.

```
$minimum_amt = $("#min_amt");
$maximum_amt = $("#max_amt");

$minimum_amt.on("change", function () {
    if ($minimum_amt.val() == '.') {
        alert("You can input only numeric number !");
    }
    if ($minimum_amt.val() > $maximum_amt.val()) {

        $(':input[name="submitDiscount"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {



        $(':input[name="submitDiscount"]').prop('disabled', false);

    }
});

$maximum_amt.on("change", function () {
    if ($maximum_amt.val() == '.') {
        alert("You can input only numeric number !");
    }
    if ($minimum_amt.val() > $maximum_amt.val()) {
        alert("Minimum Amount should be less than Maximum Amount !");
        $(':input[name="submitDiscount"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {



        $(':input[name="submitDiscount"]').prop('disabled', false);

    }
});
```

Comment: If you create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor it is easier to answer. Yo certainly do not need two functions

Comment: "How can i check ? Here is the method i check"...so there's a problem? Please describe what happens now? Apart from having two events which will execute simultaneously, do you appear to be comparing the values to each other.

Comment: "You can only input numeric number"...hmm, "numeric number" sounds like a tautology. Do you mean an "integer" (i.e a number without a decimal point))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- test that there is an input in both
- test they are numeric and not 1.  - can be done with regex too
- use on input instead of change to handle paste

```js
$(".amt").on("input", function() {
  var min = $.trim($("#min_amt").val()),
    max = $.trim($("#max_amt").val()),
    val = $.trim(this.value);
  if (val && (val.indexOf(".") !=-1 || Math.floor(val) != val || !$.isNumeric(val))) {
    alert("You can input only integers !");
    $(this).val(val.substring(0,val.length-1))
    $(this).focus();
    return
  }
  var dis = (min.length==0 || max.length==0) || ((+min) > (+max));
  $(':input[name="submitDiscount"]').prop('disabled',dis);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Min <input type="text" id="min_amt" class="amt" value="" /> 
Max <input type="text" id="max_amt" class="amt" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submitDiscount" disabled "/>
```